# What is a general way of equally spacing inline elements of the same type inside a div?

Tags: html, css

I have

```
<div class="outerdiv" id="navbar">
    <form action="page1.html"><input type="submit" value="Page 1"></form>
    <form action="page2.html"><input type="submit" value="Page 2"></form>
    <form action="page3.html"><input type="submit" value="Page 3"></form>
</div>
```

and I would like these 3 form elements to be equally spaced within the div that's wrapping them. The 3 form elements are of constant size that is small with respect to the div, so I want to keep a general CSS outline in case I need to add another form element in the future. I don't want to give separate IDs to each of the 3 elements and then float them appropriately, if I don't have to.

Comment: Can you use `display: flex` on the parent and then `flex: 1` for the form elements?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: flex` on the parent div and `flex: 1` on the form elements to stretch the form elements to cover the full width off the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/wZDPf/

```
.outerdiv {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: horisontal;
    border: solid 3px #900;
}

.outerdiv form {
    text-align: center;
    flex: 1;
    border: solid 1px #000;
}
```

Unfortunately this isn't supported by older browsers [Support table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `display:table` to the container, and `table-row` and `table-cell` elements.